# Compare two numeric range in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two number range.
Lets say 1st rage is 6-9 and second is 1-15

I need to check that if it is conflicting. I mean if 1-15 is crossing 6-9,
Valid ranges are
1-5,
10-15
but 1-15, 2-18 like this should return me that it is violating 6-9.

Currently I am checking only signle digit if it falls between range,

```
if (typeof (Number.prototype.isBetween) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.isBetween = function (min, max, notBoundaries) {
        var between = false;
        if (notBoundaries) {
            if ((this < max) && (this > min)) between = true;
            alert('notBoundaries');
        } else {
            if ((this <= max) && (this >= min)) between = true;
            alert('Boundaries');
        }
        alert('here');
        return between;
    }
}
```

But now I need to check range. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are these ranges in form of array?

Comment: lets say the second range is `a to b` ... you need to check if `a` is within the test range OR `b` is within the test range OR ( `a` is below the test range AND `b` is above the test range) ... does that help?

Comment: @anu Yes ranges are in form of array.

Comment: @JaromandaX it should check that "a to g" is not cutting first range "b to e"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of your function, I added a new function to compare ranges

```js
if (typeof (Number.prototype.isBetween) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.isBetween = function (min, max, notBoundaries) {
        var between = false;
        if (notBoundaries) {
            if ((this < max) && (this > min)) between = true;
        } else {
            if ((this <= max) && (this >= min)) between = true;
        }
        return between;
    }
}

if (typeof (Array.prototype.isRangeCrossed) === "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.isRangeCrossed = function (target,notBoundaries) {
        var result = false;
        if ((target[0].isBetween(this[0],this[1],notBoundaries) ) || (target[1].isBetween(this[0],this[1],notBoundaries))){
          result = true;
        } 
        return result;
    }
}


var range1 = [6,9];
var range2 = [1,15];
var range3 = [2,5];
console.log(range2.isRangeCrossed(range1,false));
console.log(range3.isRangeCrossed(range1,false));
```

Comment: This work well but still there is an issue like for Range1 4 to 9 And Range2 6 to 8, it is failing

Comment: [4,9] and [6,8] fails

Comment: Hmm I was wondering if checking for both will solve the issue. `range2.isRangeCrossed(range1,false)` and `range1.isRangeCrossed(range2,false)` i.e. interchanging the target and source

Comment: Or update the same function `isRangeCrossed` to check for both ranges

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure function, this should suffice:

```
var rangesOverlap = function(n1, n2, r1, r2, boundaries) {
    if (boundaries) {
        return n1 >= n2 || n2 >= r1 || r1 >= r2;
    } else {
        return n1 > n2 || n2 > r1 || r1 > r2;
    }
}
```

`n1` and `n2` are the first range, `r1` and `r2` are the second range, and `boundaries` indicate allowing overlaps on the boundary.

On the `Array` prototype, where `comp` is the 2nd range array:

```
Array.prototype.rangesOverlap = function(comp, boundaries) {
  if (boundaries) {
    return this[0] > this[1] || this[1] > comp[0] || comp[0] > comp[1];
  } else {
    return this[0] >= this[1] || this[1] >= comp[0] || comp[0] >= comp[1];
  }
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzn7vww7/2/) for a working example.

Comment: Don't understand the issue, but it always gives range overlapping, even when it is not. Can you please check again

Comment: e.g, [5,10] and [2,4] it says range overlaps

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your range checking code.

```js
if (typeof(Number.prototype.isBetween) === 'undefined') {
  Number.prototype.isBetween = function(min, max, inclusive) {
    return inclusive ? (this <= max && this >= min) : (this < max && this > min);
  }
}

var range = { min : 7, max : 12 };
var validMinInclusive = range.min.isBetween(range.min, range.max, true);
var validMaxInclusive = range.max.isBetween(range.min, range.max, true);
var invalidMinExclusive = range.min.isBetween(range.min, range.max, false);
var invalidMaxExclusive = range.max.isBetween(range.min, range.max, false);

console.log(validMinInclusive, validMaxInclusive, invalidMinExclusive, invalidMaxExclusive);
```

The following code constructs a Range object with a method for checking if another range fits inside of it. There is an inclusive flag like the one used in the above code.

```js
function Range(min, max) {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    throw 'Range must include at least one value.';
  }
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  this.min = min;
  this.max = max;
}
Range.inBounds = function(outer, inner, inclusive) {
  return inclusive
    ? (inner.min >= outer.min && inner.max <= outer.max)
    : (inner.min >  outer.min && inner.max <  outer.max);
};
Range.prototype.inBounds = function(target, inclusive) {
  return Range.inBounds(this, target, inclusive);
};

var rangeInner = new Range(6, 9);
var rangeOuter = new Range(1, 15);

var validRangeBounds   = rangeOuter.inBounds(rangeInner, false); // true
var invalidRangeBounds = rangeInner.inBounds(rangeOuter, false); // false

console.log(validRangeBounds, invalidRangeBounds);
```